# is there a way to calculate lenght of continuous gaps

Tags: python, nan, python-xarray

So, I have a list with some nan values, out of which some are continuous. e.g,
list = [1, 2, 3, np.nan, np.nan, 6, 7, np.nan, 9, np.nan,np.nan,np.nan, 12]
For some necessary reason, I'd want to get the length of individual continuous gaps.

```
def find_continuous_gaps(data):
    gap_starts = []
    gap_lengths = []
    current_gap_start = np.nan
    for i, value in enumerate(data):
        if value is np.nan:
            if current_gap_start is np.nan:
                current_gap_start = i
        else:
            if current_gap_start is not np.nan:
                gap_starts.append(current_gap_start)
                gap_lengths.append(i - current_gap_start)
                current_gap_start = np.nan
    
    if current_gap_start is not np.nan:
        gap_starts.append(current_gap_start)
        gap_lengths.append(len(data) - current_gap_start)
    
    return gap_starts, gap_lengths


# Example usage
data = [1, 2, 3, np.nan, np.nan, 6, 7, np.nan, 9, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 12]
gap_starts, gap_lengths = find_continuous_gaps(data)
gap_sum = sum_individual_gaps(gap_lengths)

print("Gap starts:", gap_starts)
print("Gap lengths:", gap_lengths)
print("Sum of individual gaps:", gap_sum)
```

results:

Gap starts: [3, 7, 9]

Gap lengths: [2, 1, 3]

Sum of individual gaps: 6

Although it does the job, is there an elegant simpler way for this.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is more suited to be asked in the  [Code Review Forum](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Code Review is a question and answer site for peer programmer code reviews. Please read the relevant guidance related to how to properly ask questions on this site before posting your question.

Comment: If I reframe my question as "find length of continuous NaN values", instead of providing working solution, will it be more apt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to specify the borders of the bool array for the two cases, the bool array is the index of the `np.nan` :

```
index_nan = np.isnan(data)
padded_for_index = np.concatenate(((False, ), index_nan, (False, )))
gap_starts = list(np.flatnonzero(padded_for_index[1:] & ~padded_for_index[:-1]))
padded_for_len = np.concatenate(([index_nan[0]],index_nan[:-1] != index_nan[1:],[True]))
gap_lengths = list(np.diff(np.where(padded_for_len)[0])[::2])
gap_sum = sum(gap_lengths)
```

This code will give you the same result as your function.